# Get a specific user field on the fly with Django context processors?

Tags: django

How could I grab a specific user object into my template? I know I can do a for loop like this if I create a context processor:

```
{% for user in users %}
    {{ user.profile.about }}
{% endfor %}
```

But that will loop through all of them. If I wanted to get a user profile field *on the fly*, how could I do that?

Something like this pseudo code below:

```
{{ user.profile.about <username> }}
```

Based on the subdomain I'm on I have got the domain that is the username as well, I want to use that to grab information about the user. How could I get the user profile with that?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. Where is `username` coming from? Why can't you send the data from the view, or the context processor?

Comment: First of all you should create function in your controller which returns specific field which you need based on specific parameters, for example `user_id`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I can send the data from the context processor, but not the view. I don't know how to write the code in the context processor to do what I want to achieve.

Comment: But you haven't really told us what you want to achieve. *Where* is username coming from? If you have that, why can't you get the user profile?

Comment: Sorry, based on the subdomain I'm on I have got the domain that is the username as well, I want to use that to grab information about the user. How could I get the user profile with that?

Comment: @JDoer please edit your question to mention this. This is an essential information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is to be used on every page within a subdomain, you can create a [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors):

> A context processor has a very simple interface: It’s just a Python function that takes one argument, an HttpRequest object, and returns a dictionary that gets added to the template context. Each context processor must return a dictionary.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def user_subdomain(request):
    host = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
    subdomain = host.split('.')[0]  # Or whatever more accurate parsing if needed
    User = get_user_model()
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=subdomain)
    return {
        'subdomain_user': user,  # avoid naming it `user` as this is
                                 # the current signed in user
    }
```

And add this context processor to your settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                ...
                'yourapp.context_processors.user_subdomain',
            ],
        },
    }
]
```

Then, in your templates, you can get this user as `{{ subdomain_user }}`.

Comment: Just one question though. If I'm not on a subdomain, how can I make it not return to context then?

Comment: You can return an empty dictionary or `{'subdomain_user': None}` if you can't find a valid subdomain. You'll also have to improve domain parsing.